# Android 4.3 doesn't show bxslider's content properly

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, bxslider

I've been stuck for 2 days and I can't find a solution.

My development enviroment:

**Cordova 3.4.0-0.1.0,jQuery v1.10.2, BxSlider v4.1.1 and Android**

When I select a category I make an ajax call and load my bxslider from the server

My code: **front**

```
$('.background_folder').on("change", function(){
        var folder = $(this).val();
        if(folder != '' && folder != undefined){

          var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            url:'http://myserver/get_backgrounds.php?folder='+folder 
          })
          .done(function( html ) {
            $('.background_sample').html(html);

            if ($(window).width() <= 320 || $(window).height() <= 480) {
              var s1 = $('.slider1').bxSlider({
                slideWidth: 230,
                minSlides: 1,
                maxSlides: 1,
                slideMargin: 10,
                pager: false
              });
            }else{
              var s2 = $('.slider1').bxSlider({
                slideWidth: 265,
                minSlides: 2,
                maxSlides: 3,
                slideMargin: 10,
                pager: false
              });  
            }
          })
          .always(function() {
            alert( "complete" );

            $('.convert').on("click", function(){
              $('.convert').css({border: '2px solid transparent'}).animate({
                opacity: 0.5
                }, 500 );
              $(this).css({border: '2px solid #f37736'}).animate({
                opacity: 1
                }, 500 );
            });
          });


        }                 
    });
```

My code: **back**

```
function get_backgrounds($folder){
    //image backgrounds
    $backgrounds = array();
    if ($handle = opendir("../backgrounds/".$folder)) {
        //$backgrounds = array();
        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            $backgrounds[] = $entry;
    }

    foreach ($backgrounds as $key => $value) {
        if($value == '.' || $value == '..'){
            unset($backgrounds[$key]);
        }
    }

}
$i = 0;
echo '<div class="slider1">';
foreach ($backgrounds as $key => $value) {
    if($i == 0){
        $selected = 'checked="checked"';
    }else{
        $selected = '';
    }

    $idvalue = 'data'.$key;

    echo '<div class="slide">';

            echo '<div class="background_thumb">';
               echo '<label class="fb" for="'.$idvalue.'">';
                   echo '<input '.$selected.' type="radio" name="background" id="'.$idvalue.'" value="'.$value.'">';
                   echo '<img class="convert" src="backgrounds/'.$folder.'/'.$value.'">';
                echo '</label>';
            echo '</div>';

        echo '</div>';
        $i++;
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

For any reason in Android 4.4.2  is fine but in Android 4.3 and lower versions the content is there but I can't see it.

**Any idea what is happening ???**

[image: select with bxslider]

[image: select]

Comment: Issue is css working incorrect several WebView. Can you post css and html after render?

Comment: The css is fine, it looks like a problem loading remote images and render in the WebView, so I think that the best solution is move the images to my app, they are small so thing not is a big size for my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly it was a CSS issue, for some reason I was losing the height, so my solution:

`$('.slider1').bxSlider({

        slideWidth: 265,
        minSlides: 2,
        maxSlides: 3,
        slideMargin: 10,
        pager: false,
        onSliderLoad: function(){
            $('.bx-viewport').css({"height":"80px !important"});
            $('.convert').css({"height":"80px !important"});
        }
    });`